# java regex - match one occurrences only

Tags: java, regex

I have this pattern "[A-Za-z -]*" that I'm using when validating input fields:

```
if (input.matches("[A-Za-z -]*")) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Basically, I'm checking if the inputs are within my field validation requirements (letters, space, and dash (allow one dash only)).  My problem is I should return true only if it has letters, space, and dash (ONE DASH only), my current code returns true even if I have inputted a lot of dashes.  How can I restrict my pattern to detect if dash exceeds one?

Comment: Does it *need* to have one dash?  Can it be composed of *only* one dash, or does it need other characters too?  Does the dash have to be in a particular position?

Answer (score 2):

The following is equivalent to your regex, except that it allows at most one dash:

```
[A-Za-z ]*-?[A-Za-z ]*
```

This matches zero or more letters/spaces, followed by at most one dash, followed by zero or more letters/spaces.

Comment: If the dash appear at the start/end, will it be able to detect it?

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing a dash.

```
if(input.indexOf('-') != 0) input.replaceFirst("-", " ");
```

Then, since you've only removed one dash, you can run your regex query without checking for hyphens. If one exists, the query will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look ahead anchored at start of input:

```
^(?!(.*-){2})[A-Za-z -]*
```